# How to use update in django admin with custom function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I am trying to make an admin action to update the price of an asset. It firsts set the last_update_date to today/now and I want to set the last_price to the current market price.
The last part is not working as it is not updating.

#### admin.py:

```
@admin.action(description='Update asset price')
def update_price(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(last_update_date = timezone.now())
    for q in queryset:
        q.last_price = get_close_price(q.ticker) #does not change anything


class AssetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [update_price]

admin.site.register(Asset, AssetAdmin)
```

#### models.py:

```
class Asset(models.Model):

    ticker = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Ticker",
        max_length=5,
        unique=True,
    )

    last_price = models.DecimalField(
        verbose_name="Last Price",
        max_digits=8,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
    )

    last_update_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Last update date"
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ticker']
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.ticker
```

#### Custom function (from Alpha Advantage API)

```
def get_close_price(SYMBOL):
    params["symbol"] = SYMBOL
    close_price = get(URL, params).json()
    close_price = close_price["Global Quote"]["05. price"]
    return close_price #returns an int
```

Comment: You did not `save()`.

Comment: Thank you and Damoiskii, I had the misconception that you only save when you create a object but not when you modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're updating the `last_update_date` field using the `update()` on the queryset at the line:

```
queryset.update(last_update_date = timezone.now())
```

That's updating the value for each field in that given queryset. But as for the `last_price` field, this is not updating because you're not calling the `save()` as pointed out by @KlauseD. What you need to add is:

```
for q in queryset:
    q.last_price = get_close_price(q.ticker)
    q.save() # to save the updated price
```

Ideally, that should work.